# How do I make a trace table to find (print) the smallest value of three given integers?

Tags: python, integer, trace

I'm trying to print the smallest of three given (e.g. 4,6,2) values by making a trace table and a corresponding flowchart, but I have no idea where to begin. The trace table has five columns: 'statement,' 'a', 'b,' 'c,' and 'smallest.'

Where do I begin? Also, would it change if two of the values are the same (e.g. 4,6,4), or if one of them is negative (4,6,-4)?

Comment: What  are you trying to do, to find the minimum among three integers? If so, wouldn't `min(a, min(b,c))` do what you want?

Comment: @dcg `min(a, b, c)` would work fine too.

Comment: @gmds That's right!

Comment: @dcg and @ gmds: I don't think the point is to do this exercise with the minimal amount of Python code.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! 

The point of this exercise however, is to make a trace table to test(?) what would be my algorithm, and a flowchart. I think we're supposed to try to put in different integer values to learn how to find the smallest out of them.

Comment: @MinahWon What would the format of your table be? (.e.g a nested `list` or `dict`)

Comment: We just have to fill it out on paper, to practice! Same goes for the flowchart.